# CEDET overriding color theme

Tags: emacs

In my .emacs file I have:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "emacs/site/jde/lisp"))
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "emacs/site/cedet/common"))
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "emacs/site/cedet/semantic"))
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "emacs/site/cedet/speedbar"))
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "emacs/site/cedet/eieio"))
    (setq jde-check-version-flag nil)
(load-file (expand-file-name "emacs/site/cedet/common/cedet.el"))
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "emacs/site/elib"))

(require 'jde)

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/elisp")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/elisp/color-theme")
(require 'color-theme)
  (color-theme-initialize)
  (color-theme-clarity)
```

The top half runs JDEE, and the second half gets me the clarity color theme. My problem is, when I use JDEE, the colors for Java text revert back to what they were before I applied the color theme. This is a problem because the default colors are awful, and I'd like to have my color theme apply no matter what. Is there any way to make the color theme take priority over JDEE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see in JDEE sources, it uses its own faces for Java source text, not standard font-lock faces. You need to customize JDEE faces by using `M-x customize-group jde-java-font-lock-faces` command... Another way to update them - add code that will assign value of standard font-lock faces to variables like `jde-java-font-lock-number-face` (full list is at `jde-java-font-lock.el` file), although JDEE defines more faces than font-lock provides.

P.S. One comment regarding loading of CEDET - if you're using `cedet.el` to load CEDET, then it will set `load-path` accordingly, so you don't need to update it manually.